# babel transform throw error ERROR in The node API for `babel` has been moved to `babel-core` n sublime-text3

Tags: sublimetext3, babeljs, eslint

I have installed ***babel-core*** globally and ***babel-eslint*** both globally and locally in one of the angular project in macOS *10.12.6* and trying to check the functionality os babel and eslint in sublime -text3 (build *3143*)

```
npm install -g babel-cli
npm install -g babel-eslint --save-dev
```

also installed below sublime-text3 packages  to run and lint js file

- [Bable](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Babel)
- [esLint](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/esLint)
- [sublimeLinter-contrib-eslint](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-contrib-eslint)
- [sublimeLinter-contrib-jshint](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-contrib-jshint)

also have *.eslintrc* and *.jshintrc* file in project root directory and it is linting the js code fine so far

*.eslintrc*  file has below content

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "extends": "eslint:recommended"
    // other rules and global variables
}
```

Now navigate into sublime text and and click **Tools > Babel > Babel Transform** for the js file and it immediately throw errors as below

```
Error: /opt/project/node_modules/babel/index.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { throw new Error("The node API for `babel` has been moved to `babel-core`.");
                                                          ^

Error: The node API for `babel` has been moved to `babel-core`.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/project/node_modules/babel/index.js:1:69)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /Users/keshav.m/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Babel/babel-transform.js:23:29
    at /Users/keshav.m/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Babel/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:44:21
```

Someone please suggest me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

fixed this issue by executing these 2 commands from project root directory

```
sudo npm uninstall babel --save-dev
sudo npm install babel-loader babel-core --save-dev
```